# python, virtualenv - trying to make a new virtualenv and getting error

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to make a virtualenv and am a noob. I'm  not sure if I'm doing this correctly or if I have a wonked setup.

I do:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/
mkvirtualenv test1
Sat Mar 17$ mkvirtualenv test1
New python executable in test1/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............done.
Installing pip...............done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
Sat Mar 17$
```

I'm on OS X 10.7.2. and python 2.7.2 that was installed via brew.

any ideas? Not sure if I should just start over or how to do it.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your virtualenvwrapper is incorrectly installed.